# Magento export to CSV File shows "Error 503"

Tags: magento, export, export-to-csv

Good morning.

I've been having this issue for some days and have been lokking for a solution, but I haven't found one yet.

The problem is, I have this Magento store and some grids can be exported to CSV files, while others shows:
Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:

XID: 853411302

---

Varnish cache server

The Magento version I'm using is 1.6.2. I guess the problem is not about PHP code, since the error shown is this generic error, instead of a PHP one (I even found the code used for exporting files and it seems to be ok).
I would like to know why is this error being showed to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Varnish Cache related error, I would suggest following the guide below on how to identify what the XID is returning for more insight on how to fix the issue:

- https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/troubleshooting.html#varnish-gives-me-guru-meditation

Comment: Thanks, sir. I'll try to find the answer using this link. I'll leave this thread unresolved for now, because if I can't find a solution through this I'll probably be back with other questions. If I find a way to solve my problem, I'll be back to mark your post as an answer ASAP.

Comment: I'm marking as an answer since it's the closest I've ever been to a solution so far. I still haven't solved the problem, but this gave me a lead to go on.